# How to change Mina NioProcessor thread names

Tags: apache-mina, mina

I want to change mina NioProcessor thread names because when I print thread names using log4j, they aren't very meaningful to me  (e.g. NioProcessor-36, NioProcessor-42) especially when there are multiple Processors around. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below solution offers custom thread names after NioProcessor threads.

1. Create a custom thread factory which gives your desired names to new threads. [Here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/Executors.java#Executors.DefaultThreadFactory) is an example how to do this.
2. Create an executor filter like below

   ```
   Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1, new YourThreadFactory("namingConvention"))
   acceptor.getFilterChain().addFirst("executor", executor)
   ```

If you already have an executor filter, then you will just give a thread factory as parameter.